# Objective-C wait for asynchronous HTTP-Request to finish

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, nsurlconnection, httprequest

I use the following code to execute a HTTP-Request:

```
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
```

After that I want to use the received data. My problem is that i can't do this in connectionDidFinishLoading, but have to do this on another position in my code. As this is an asynchronous task, how can I verify that I don't start to use the received data before the task is completely done?

Thanks in advance,

Edit: My main problem is that the delegates are called after the code which uses the received data.

Comment: Is there a reason `connectionDidFinishLoading:` can't just call the relevant section of your code?

Answer (score 2):

you just have to keep the received data in an ivar an use it whenever you want. if you really want to be sure, you can also use a BOOL set to YES in

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

don't forget that since iOS 5, the NSURLConnectionDelegate (and DownloadDelegate) have changed.

Comment: i currently keep the received data in an ivar. I also tried to use a flag (bool) to get the information if the delegate was called. Here i have the problem that i end up in an endless loop if I check the bool with `while([NSURLClassXY boolvar]){} ...following code...`

Comment: here the snippet I use for my unit test when I'm waiting for a download to complete:

    `NSRunLoop *theRL = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    while (!self.downloadComplete && [theRL runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]]);`

It does the trick. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Download the AFNetworking library and use it for your connections. It has blocks methods, which (to me) are much 'cleaner' to use instead of delegate methods. AFNetworking is available on iOS 4 and higher.

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Read this post on some basics of AFNetworking:

http://engineering.gowalla.com/2011/10/24/afnetworking/